# Make responsive navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make responsive navbar dropdown that when the website open in mobile the dropdown menu full screen. But when i try to make it to the right with "right: 0" it just go to the right of the toogle button. How to make it go to the right of screen and full screen?. I am use Bootstrap 4

```
<!-- Grup Tombol -->
<div class="col-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end custom-grup-tombol">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Chat -->
    <div class="nav-item btn-group pl-1 ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block rounded" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Chat -->
    <!-- Notif -->
    <div class="nav-item btn-group pl-1 ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block rounded" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Notif -->
    <!-- User-->
    <div class="nav-item btn-group pl-1 ">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-block rounded" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!-- End User--> 
  </div>           
</div>
<!-- END Grup Tombol -->
```

[The Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0tY9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, these tips may help:

To make `dropdown-menu` attached right, you can add the following lines to your style:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  top: calc(2em + 2rem + 2px) !important;
  right: 0 !important;
}
.nav-item, .btn-group>.btn, .navbar, div.justify-content-end.custom-grup-tombol {
  position: static !important;
}
```

Also, I recommend you to break a line of the `dropdown-item`s with long text by adding

```css
.dropdown-item {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: this is the codepen https://codepen.io/david-noya/pen/JjGOXPp

Comment: @DavidNoya I have modified the answer in a way, it works in codepen

Comment: thanks dude, now i just need to make it full screen. Thank you very much

Comment: sorry but i just test it again. it just go to far right of navbar not the far right of the screen. is there any way to make it right on the screen?

Comment: You may add relative position to the last icon in a row and remove it from ‘navbar’ class.

Comment: @DavidNoya Did it help?

Comment: Nope, its make the display more messy

Comment: @DavidNoya Edited once again. (removed all relative positioning in upper layers)